# Python Script Not Showing All Rows in Email

Tags: python

I wrote a script that would look into all subfolders for a directory and compare their date modified value to the current timestamp. If its great than 30 minutes then it would send me an email. If there is more than one string returned it sends me the same amount of emails. How can i put all the results in one email instead of it sending me multiple emails for multiple subfolders?

Output now :
**Email 1:**
C:\Test\Test: 00:30:00
**Email 2:**
C:\Test\Test2: 00:30:00
**Email 3:**
C:\Test\Test3: 00:30:00

Expected output:
**One email:** 
C:\Test\Test: 00:30:00
C:\Test\Test2: 00:30:00
C:\Test\Test3: 00:30:00

```
 import os
 import time
 import sys
 from datetime import date
 from datetime import datetime
 from datetime import timedelta
 import win32com.client as win32

 print("There are folders inside GOXSA2016 for longer than 30 minutes. Please 
 login to server and 
 check for errors. See duration time periods below")
 for root, folders, files in os.walk('N:\OCRFF\import'):
     for name in folders:
         datetimeFormat = '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S.%f'
         filedate = datetime.fromtimestamp(os.path.getmtime(os.path.join(root, 
         name)))
         now_time = datetime.now()
         now_time = str(now_time)
         filedate = str(filedate)
         now_time = datetime.strptime(now_time, datetimeFormat)
         filedate = datetime.strptime(filedate, datetimeFormat)
         difference = now_time-filedate
         if difference > timedelta(seconds=1) and os.path.join(root, name)=='N:\\OCRFF\\import':
             break
         if difference > timedelta(seconds=1):
             file_times = os.path.join("\\\Test\Test2" + root.strip("N:"), name),": 
         ",str(difference)
             file_times_final = file_times[0] + file_times[1] + file_times[2]

             outlook = win32.Dispatch('outlook.application')
             mail = outlook.CreateItem(0)
             mail.To = 'test@test.com'
             mail.Subject = '**CORRESPONDENCE ALERT**'

             mail.HTMLBody = f"""
                        There are folders inside that arelonger than 30 
             minutes. Please login to server and 
                        check for errors. See duration time period below for 
             the folder path.<br/><br/>"""

             mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody + file_times_final + """<br/>"""
             mail.HTMLBody = mail.HTMLBody + '''<br /><br /> Thank You, <br /> 
                 Payment 
             Processing Center<br />'''

             mail.Send()
```

Comment: Your mail sending code is *inside* the loop. Gather all results first and only then send your mail.

Comment: @usr2564301 If i take it out of the loop it will only send one email with only one row. If i put it back in the for loop i get all my rows but in separate emails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are many ways to do this.  A simple way is to make file_times_final a list and append to it, then send one email outside the loop like was suggested.

After your import add `file_times_final = []` this is an empty list declaration.  You can store anything inside a list with list.append(input)

So instead of `file_times_final = file_times[0] + file_times[1] + file_times[2]` make it 
`file_times_final.append(file_times[0] + file_times[1] + file_times[2])`  This just says append to your list those times every time the loop hits.

Then take out your email code outside of the loop and the result should be a comma separated list with brackets `[]` surrounding it.  You can play with the output format.